# Version issues with the wit python package on openshift

Tags: python, openshift

I'm building a python app in [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/). I want to use the [wit](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit) package, but the highest version it supports is only 1.1 I think. The most recent version of wit is 3.5.0. I understand Openshift uses a mirror for the PyPI packages and it updates quickly, but it doesn't seem to be the case for the wit package. Any ideas how to get access to the most recent wit package in openshift?

By the way, I configured the dependency in the setup.py file

```
install_requires=[..., 'wit>=3.4.0']
```

And I get this error when I push to openshift

```
remote: Searching for wit>=3.4.0
remote: Reading http://mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com/mirror/python/web/simple/wit/
remote: No local packages or download links found for wit>=3.4.0
remote: error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('wit>=3.4.0')
```

Comment: This happened to me also the other day when trying to install a package. It would not find the specific package on Openshift but worked fine on my localhost.  I ended up ssh I to my app,  activated my virtual env and did an easy_install.

Comment: That seems like a good idea. Although in my case, wit just used a single file so I decided to include it directly into my project. I'll stick with that until a newer version of wit is available in the mirror.